# Windows PC as USB Host communicating over USB with Android Device

Tags: android, windows, usb, winusb

i would like to transfer data (programmatically) over USB from an Android App to a Server on a Windows PC. I´ve searched the web for over 3-4 days and couldn´t find any sample code, etc.

Is there any way to realize this in Java, C#, etc? I´ve established a connection via adb, but adb isn´t an option.

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer , but I am assuming the issue is still unsolved. If not , please ignore. I have used ADB to communicate : refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21749521/1833437) for additonal details.

Answer (score 0):

use rxtx for pc side(http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
and use android usb api
(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html) for android side after installing device usb drivers