# Can I connect an Android phone via USB cable to a Windows desktop to send/receive text messages?

Tags: android, .net, windows, sms, nexus-5

I am pretty new to Android, so bear with me. I've done a good deal of C#/C++ coding for Windows and some for iOS. But I've never done Android.

So I was wondering what do I need to connect an Android phone (we have Google Nexus 5X) directly to a Windows desktop via a cable and then send/receive text messages through it?

I'm assuming that I will need to code an interface app on the phone and then write a .NET module for Windows integration, for as long as the "connection" part is not proprietary.

PS. I know that there are online services that allow to send text messages for a small fee, but that's not what I'm interested in here. In my case I'm planning to integrate this capability with some additional software that we use here in the office.

Comment: That depends entirely upon what you're expecting to do with the cable. Other than for developer tools, the cable is not used for anything in conventional Android development. We usually connect Android devices with desktop/notebook OSes using WiFi, Bluetooth, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a message from Android to Windows using USB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748790/how-to-send-a-message-from-android-to-windows-using-usb)

Comment: This seems to be the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748790/how-to-send-a-message-from-android-to-windows-using-usb