# How to use libusb to transfer bytes from android host to another machine which runs on windows

Tags: android, linux, windows, libusb, libusb-1.0

I am developing android application where I need to transfer bytes from android device (host) to another device which runs on windows via USB.

I came across [libusb](https://github.com/libusb/libusb) library which only works on host mode, so I am developing an android application for android tablet which will act as host and need to communicate with a machine where windows OS runs.

Machine which runs windows always act as host, correct me If I am wrong?

So in my case both are host so things are not going to work. Afaik, in a communication one need to be a host and rest peripherals.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work ?

Comment: If your phone must be a client I can see couple ways of communication, it depends on how many data you need to transfer.

Comment: You going to "root" your android device?

Comment: @once2go Just few bytes I need to transfer.

Comment: @user1034749 I will do if there is any work around only for rooted devices.

Comment: @user1034749 do you know something that will work for rooted device ?

Comment: On rooted devices Android become fully controlled Linux, so you for example you can remove default usb handling code and load https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt so windows see you device as com port, and using standard API you can transfer bytes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749521/3612976 does this suitable for you? 
Or this app must be in production(in play market)?

Comment: Yep, I did some kinda